# VLP-16 pointcloud data has angular gap in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, vlp-16, velodyne-pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I am using VLP-16 and ros for SLAM.

When I see the captured pcap file in VeloView I can see the scans correctly.
But when I try to publish it on Rviz, in each scan part of the data(from specific angle for around 30 degree) are lost.
In each scan the angle of lost points changes.
I also tried to save the scan in other program and realized that the saved point cloud also have the same gap.
The rotation speed of velodyne was 600 rpm.
I am using ros-indigo and for showing data in rviz I am using following commands:

```
rviz -f velodyne

roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch calibration:="VLP-16.yaml"

rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=./velodyne_scan.pcap _read_once:=true
```

Here is the video of my scan in rviz.

https://youtu.be/cNrVzr3vcFk

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250227/vlp-16-pointcloud-data-has-angular-gap-in-rviz-!!/) by [Ehsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28828/ehsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-20**:
I haven't had time to look into your issue very much, but it might be related to this: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/689

**Comment by [Ehsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28828/ehsan/) on 2016-12-22**:
Thank you William.
I checked this post but I think it's not related to my issue.
I uploaded the video from my rviz here.

https://youtu.be/cNrVzr3vcFk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There may be some start-up delays causing part of the data to be lost. Try it without the `read_once` option.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ehsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28828/ehsan/) on 2016-12-20**:
Thank you Jack for your reply. I tried without `read_once` option but still I have the same problem. Lost data (gap) is not only for the first scan. In each scan I have the same gap with different starting angle. The starting angle of gap rotating with 1Hz.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-12-23**:
In that case, why do you think it's not the rviz problem @William mentioned?